# Syntax error when setting trigger on MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I have a problem in setting a trigger on a MySQL database with PHPMyAdmin. Here is the trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
AFTER INSERT ON `tableToMonitor` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   DECLARE `recordExists` TINYINT;
   IF NEW.`field1` = "stringValue" THEN
       SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO `recordExists`
       FROM `table1`
       WHERE (`field2` = NEW.`field2`) AND (`field3` = NEW.`field3`);
    
       IF recordExists = 1 THEN
           UPDATE `table1`
           SET `field4` = 1 
           WHERE (`field2` = NEW.`field2`) AND (`field3` = NEW.`field3`);
       ELSE
           INSERT INTO table1 (`field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field6`, `field7`, `field8`, `field9`)
           VALUES (NEW.`field2`, NEW.`field3`, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
       END IF;
    END IF;
END //
```

When I try to set the trigger, I have the following error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 20

I can't find the error, can someone help me?

Comment: `END//` - remove the space

Comment: Have you tried running it via the commandline client to see if it runs smoothly?

Comment: Yeah, try using `END//` then reset the delimiter back to semi column: `DELIMITER ;`.

Comment: I tried to remove the space on `END //` and add a `DELIMITER ;` on the last line. Now I have a `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//' at line 20`

Comment: The error I get in phpmyadmin is #1146 - Table 'sandbox.tableToMonitor' doesn't exist which is expected since I don't have that table - so no syntax error , what is the default delimiter you have set in phpmyadmin?